# Atributo hidden em elemento <span></span> não funciona?

Tags: html, html5

Salve!
Acredito que seja uma dúvida meio básica, mas vá lá.
Numa das views da aplicação é montada uma tabela e na coluna mais à direita são incluídos dois elementos to tipo *span*. Ao último eu incluí o atributo **hidden (hidden="hidden")**. No entanto o elemento é mostrado, conforme pode ser visto no seguinte fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/6fswhgd3/.

Obviamente não desejo usar o recurso de estilizar o *span* conforme fiz na última linha da tabela do exemplo.

O que posso fazer?
Grato pela atenção de todos.
Paulo Ricardo Ferreira

Comment: Não existe atributo hidden. Se você quer ocultar o `span` use `css` - `display: none`

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior, De acordo com o site [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_span.asp) existe o atributo hidden. Obrigado.

Comment: De fato existe no HTML5 Paulo. Eu acredito que o seu problema seja porque a classe do `bootstrap` - `glyphicon` altera o display do elemento para `inline` assim que o css é carregado.

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior, de fato, a classe Glyphicon altera o display para inline-block. Obrigado.

Comment: Publique uma resposta com a solução encontrada, se outros usuários tiverem o mesmo problema, saberão o que foi feito para resolver. :)

Comment: @PedroCamaraJunior, ambas as respostas abaixo resolvem o problema.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

De acordo com o codigo que voce enviou no fillde, a sua tag span deveria ter algo parecido com isso:

`<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" style="display:none"></span>`

Para mais detalhes:
http://jsfiddle.net/6fswhgd3/1/

Comment: Thiago, eu sei, tanto que na 3ª linha da tabela eu usei esse recurso, mas só para testar. Mas, como postei na minha dúvida, não gostaria de usar esse recurso por conta do que desejo fazer na interface. Obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar esse código no Html:

```
  <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-refresh" id = "ak"></span>
```

> No Html eu criei um Id para esse span para poder editar ele no CSS.

E criar um CSS com o código:

```
 #ak { visibility:hidden }
```

Vai ficar como nesse fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7bvqc0er/1/